# Transfer folder to AWS Ubuntu server. Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, scp

I installed shiny server on an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance following instruction here: https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/

I tried to transfer a folder to a remote directory: /srv/shiny-server 
by typing in terminal:

```
scp -r path/Publickey path/folder ubuntu@ec2-52-15-128-161.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/srv/shiny-server
```

Then I got:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the key that was being used is not accepted for the user `ubuntu` on your server. If `path/Publickey` is your key and the key is in `~ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys`, you'll need the `-i` flag. Without it, ssh will look in the user's default (i.e. `~/.ssh/id_rsa`). This should do it:

```
scp -i path/Publickey -r path/folder ubuntu@ec2-52-15-128-161.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/srv/shiny-server
```

Comment: I checked the ~ubuntu/.ssh and the authorized_keys indeed is there. Then I run your  command but get: scp: /srv/shiny-server/mdminer: Permission denied. At least it looks like I have got a step closer, and what can I do next?

Comment: It looks like it is now authenticating, but the ubuntu user doesn't have permission to write to that folder. First, make sure it exists, then ubuntu has rwx permissions. After that, you should be good!

Comment: I rewrite it with chmod 777 and it's fine now!